# Does room-compiler support FILTER clause?

Tags: android, sqlite, count, android-sqlite, android-room

I define Room Dao with Query like this:

```
@Query(
   "SELECT " + 
   "COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE f > 1) as count1 " +
   "FROM myTable WHERE ..."
)
```

and get an error:

> extraneous input '(' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE,
> K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP,
> K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE,
> K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES,
> K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

I suppose the compiler doesn't understand '(' after FILTER keyword.
I use `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.1"` in my build.gradle.
I have shown the simplified query, in the real one, I have more than one `COUNT(*)` fields and cannot move `WHERE` after `FROM`.

I used the aggregator syntax from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`FILTER`](https://sqlite.org/syntax/filter-clause.html) clause for aggregate functions is supported by SQLite since version 3.30.0 (2019-10-04).
This version of SQLite is used by Android only for API Level 31+ (which is currently the latest).
This means that if your code runs in a device with a lower API Level you will not be able to use this new feature.

An alternative would be conditional aggregation:

```
@Query(
   "SELECT " + 
   "COUNT(CASE WHEN f > 1 THEN 1 END) AS count1 " +
   "FROM myTable WHERE ..."
)
```

or with [`TOTAL()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) aggregate function:

```
@Query(
   "SELECT " + 
   "TOTAL(f > 1) AS count1 " +
   "FROM myTable WHERE ..."
)
```